# Why can't delete but can add to CoreData?

Tags: core-data, swift3

The following code does save an item to CoreData:

```
    var elements:[Elements]
    elements = try managedObjectContext.fetch(itemsFetch) as! [Elements]

    do {
        elements.append(el)
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to save an element", error)
    }
```

The following does remove an element. I see in the debugger that the elements count goes down by one.

```
    elements.remove(at: 5)
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error deleting element")
    }
```

But when I stop the app and restart, the old element is back. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example appends the element to the data source array. The item is added to Core Data with `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName:into` somewhere else.

In the same way you have to remove the element from the data source array and also from Core Data

```
let elementToRemove = elements[5]
managedObjectContext.delete(elementToRemove)
elements.remove(at: 5)
```

Comment: I don't think that is correct. You should be able to work with the array only and just call managedObjectContext.save() after you have manipulated the array.

Comment: It is correct. The `elements` array is not in sync with Core Data.

Comment: @4thSpace It's correct. If you think you should be able to do it differently, [file a bug with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: The array should be in sync. That's the whole point of using the array. I've added some additional code to the OP that shows this. Also, why isn't the the `managedObjectContext.add()` call needed for the array `append()` to work. The `append()` code as is works fine.

Comment: Believe me, it is not. You need the array because Core Data uses a `Set` internally to store the data. Calling `save` after a `fetch` is useless because the fetch does not change the data base. What is `managedObjectContext.add()`? There is no `add` API in the `NSManagedObjectContext` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
var elements: [NSManagedObject] = []
//Delete from core data
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
  UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! 
  AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
 if editingStyle == .delete {
   let element = elements[indexPath.row]
   context.delete(element)
  (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
 do {
   elements = try context.fetch(YOUR_ENTITY_NAME.fetchRequest())
} catch {
   print(error)
  }
}
    tableView.reloadData()
    }
```